# Giving a new attribute to a vertex

Tags: java, attributes, inner-classes

I am given an implementation code for a vertex interface of a graph. My goal is to make each vertex hold an additional attribute (e.g. its position in a positional list) **without** altering the original code.

- I 've seen a lot of people suggesting the use of a `HashMap` with the vertex as a key and the new attribute as its value, but HashMaps have a worst case complexity of O(n). I need to be able to to retrive the vertex's new attribute in O(1) worst case.
- The first thing I tried was extending the implementation of the vertex with a new subclass. But the original vertex implementation is given in a private nested class inside the graph's implemantation class and therefore I cannot access it. I was wondering if maybe there is a way to "re-implement" the vertex interface with the final vertex object keeping the properties of both implementations, but I do not think that is possible.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should still consider using HashMap because in most cases it is O(1), but here is my solution for your problem by creating a new class, **without altering the original code**.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


class GivenVertex {
    private:
        int color = 3;
        int ord;
        // ...
    public:
        GivenVertex() {}

        int getClr() {
            return color;
        }

};

class MyVertex {
    public:
        int position;
        GivenVertex V;

        MyVertex(GivenVertex V, int position) {
            this->V = V;
            this->position = position;
        }
};

int main() {
    GivenVertex GV = GivenVertex();
    
    // You can create you vertex like this
    int pos = 7;
    MyVertex MV = MyVertex(GV, pos);

    // to check if this works
    assert(MV.V.getClr() == 3);
    assert(pos == MV.position);

    cout << MV.V.getClr() << " " << MV.position << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

The idea is simple - you create a new class, which will have your private class and your new variable as you call position.

Or you can create a child class and using inheritance will do its work and also code will be "pro", but I prefer a simple way to do it. If you want you can check inheritance here: [Inheritance in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-c/)

***EDIT:***
Update according to the comment, let's try inheritance, I think that should work.
Create a new subclass of the given Vertex class, but it'll take to rewrite all the methods you need to use in MyVertex. (I suppose there should be some way to improve this part too). Hope that will help.

```
class GivenVertex {
    private:
        int color = 3;
    public:
        GivenVertex() {}

        int getGivenClr() {
            return color;
        }

};

class MyVertex : private GivenVertex {
    public:
        int position;

        MyVertex(int position) {
            this->position = position;
        }

        int getMyClr() {
            return getGivenClr();
        }

};

int main() {
    // You can create your vertex like this
    int pos = 7;
    MyVertex MV = MyVertex(pos);

    // to check if this works
    assert(MV.getMyClr() == 3);
    assert(pos == MV.position);

    cout << MV.getMyClr() << " " << MV.position << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer! Maybe I should have mentioned it, but I tried this aproach as well. The problem with this aproach is that the new class MyVertex lacks the properties given to the vertex from the graph. For example, `g.adjacent(v)` will return an iterable of all the adjacent Vertices of GivenVertex gV in Graph g. With this aproach, you have no way of getting an iterable of all the adjacent Vertices of MyVertex mV in Graph g.

Comment: Correction: ...of all the adjacent Vertices of Vertex v (implemented with GivenVertex) in Graph g.

Comment: Hi, yea that changes a solution I guess, but how about inheritance now?! I've got no more ideas, hope this last one works ;) - see the EDIT.

Comment: `class MyVertex : private GivenVertex` I am not sure if java allows this to happen, especially given the fact that GivenVertex is not only private but also nested inside the class Graph. Not so fond of this aproach, as I do not want my professor to think I found a loophole in the "no altering the original code" rule, but it sure is a great idea. Thanks a lot for the feedback!